# Do I need to use mkl_malloc for a Intel_mkl program?

Tags: intel-mkl

I'm learning to write program with Intel mkl, in the sample codes 'mkl_malloc' and 'mkl_free' are used, and I tried to replace them with 'malloc' and 'free', the program still worked. So, do I need to use the mkl's version?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't strictly *need* to use the MKL memory functions. Your code will run without errors if you do so. However, for best performance and reproducible results, you *should* supply the MKL library with data aligned on 64-byte boundaries, and the MKL memory functions are a convenient way to do this.

Here's a [reference to performance](https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/438652):

> To improve performance of your application that calls Intel MKL, align
>   your arrays on 64-byte boundaries and ensure that the leading
>   dimensions of the arrays are divisible by 64.

And a [reference to reproducibility](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/getting-reproducible-results-with-intel-mkl):

> One of the ways Intel MKL gets good performance is through use of new
>   instructions made available with successive generations of Intel®
>   processors. Some of these instructions make computation more efficient
>   by performing the same floating point operation on multiple floating
>   point numbers at once. The way some of these instructions are loaded
>   however depends on how the data is situated in memory. If in one run
>   of the program, the data happens to be aligned along a 16-byte
>   boundary, then the first 2 double precision numbers in the array would
>   be grouped together, while in the next run, if the array is offset
>   from that memory boundary, then the 2nd and 3rd double precision
>   numbers are grouped together.  This difference in order can cause
>   different results when running the same program two times
>   consecutively with all settings remaining identical.

The differences with unaligned data (if any) can depend on the particular CPU you are using, and I believe that the impact is not as great on recent processors as it was in previous generations. Even so, it's probably still a good idea to align your data if at all possible.